# my values on one column wont update immediately after inserting data, but after refresh the values shows up

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, model-view-controller

after I inserting data, what shows on the column table "Jumlah Hasil Perah" shows '0'. but after refreshing the browser, the value shows up the result.

here's the code

Model (m_hasilperah):

```
public function jumlahPerahSapi($id)
{   
    $this->db->select('hasilPerahPagi, hasilPerahSore');
    $this->db->where('idSapi', $id);
    $cek = $this->db->get('tb_hasilperah');
    if ($cek) {
        $this->db->set('jumlahPerah', "hasilPerahPagi + hasilPerahSore", FALSE);
        $this->db->where('idSapi', $id);
        $this->db->update('tb_hasilperah');
    }
    return false;
}
```

Controller

```
public function tambahHasilPerah(){
    $idSapi = $this->input->post('idSapi');
    $tglPerah = $this->input->post('tglPerah');
    $hasilPerahPagi = $this->input->post('hasilPerahPagi');
    $hasilPerahSore = $this->input->post('hasilPerahSore');
    $jumlahPerah = $this->m_hasilperah->jumlahPerahSapi($idSapi);;

    $data =
        [
            'idSapi' => $idSapi,
            'tglPerah' => $tglPerah,
            'hasilPerahPagi' => $hasilPerahPagi,
            'hasilPerahSore' => $hasilPerahSore,
            'jumlahPerah' => $jumlahPerah
        ];
    $insert = $this->m_hasilperah->tambahHasilPerahModel($data, $idSapi);
    if ($insert) {
        redirect('C_hasilperah/tampilHasilPerah/' . $idSapi, 'refresh');
    } else {
        echo 'gagal';
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[View after insert(before manual refresh)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjT9Q.png)

[View after manual refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6aAC.png)

Comment: first goes through the basic if you writing normal code which executes after page loading then your data will load after page loading. If you want data without page loading you have to use ajax.

Comment: I think I'm very confident with the "redirect('C_hasilperah/tampilHasilPerah/' . $idSapi, 'refresh')" part there... I'm not planning to use ajax... just want to know why the values need to be refreshed in order to show up the result. bcs on other functions I don't need to do that. so I think the problem is in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Your Model method jumlahPerahSapi() every time returned false. Even if after the data update. Please look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Your Model function `jumlahPerahSapi($id)` is always return `false` even inserted successfully in DB.
So This is not run `redirect('C_hasilperah/tampilHasilPerah/' . $idSapi, 'refresh');`
Every time run `echo 'gagal';`
Modify the model function as follows.

```
public function jumlahPerahSapi($id)
{   
    $this->db->select('hasilPerahPagi, hasilPerahSore');
    $this->db->where('idSapi', $id);
    $cek = $this->db->get('tb_hasilperah');
    if ($cek) {
        $this->db->set('jumlahPerah', "hasilPerahPagi + hasilPerahSore", FALSE);
        $this->db->where('idSapi', $id);
        $this->db->update('tb_hasilperah');
        
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```